# ¿Qué quiere decir «cintura sola»?

Tags: expresiones, modismos, letras-de-canciones

Esta letra es de la canción «Danza kuduro» por Don Omar:

> Las manos arriba, **cintura sola** 
> Da media vuelta, Danza Kuduro

Busqué una explicación/definición en Google, pero no encontré nada.  ¿Qué quiere decir? Quizás describa una inclinación de bailar…

Comment: Creo que simplemente se le faltó el artículo por quedar mejor con el ritmo. O sea, debe haber sido "Las manos arriba, la cintura sola da media vuelta" porque así se entiende.

Comment: @nopaltepec Entonces ¿qué es una «cintura sola»? Eso no me tiene sentido.

Comment: La cintura sola da media vuelta, o sea solamente la cintura se mueve, con las manos arriba y el resto del cuerpo quieto. Entiendo que está describiendo un baile.

Answer (score 1):

These seem to be dance step instructions for placement of the hands, similar to the American square dance. One hand up, one on the waist; both hands up, cintura sola.
Not having seen the dance, this is simply an intuitive response.

Comment: Seems plausible. Unfortunately this can’t be confirmed by the music video because not one media vuelta was dada with manos arriba.